# Spin an AWS EC2 Spot instance with some validity using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to spin an AWS EC2 Spot instance with some validity (For example, Spot created should be accessible for  2hours or 3hours and the Spot instance should be terminated). 
I am able to spin the spot instance using the below code but unable to set the duration/validity of the created Spot instance.

I am sharing my Terraform code (both main.tf and variable.tf) by which I am trying to spin a spot instance.
I tried to set the the expiry of the Spot instance using the below 2 lines of code in my main.tf file but did't work

```
  valid_until = "${var.spot_instance_validity}"
  terminate_instances_with_expiration = true
```

For `valid_until` , I couldn't able to give the RFC3339 format or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ - calculating for 2 hour from the time when I spin the Spot instance. So removed the above 2 lines of code from my main.tf file

Below is the my main.tf file used to spin the spot instance

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
  region     = "${var.region}"
}

resource "aws_spot_instance_request" "dev-spot" {
  ami = "${var.ami_web}"
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  subnet_id = "subnet-xxxxxx"
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  key_name = "${var.key_name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-xxxxxxx"]
  spot_price                      = "${var.linux_spot_price}"
  wait_for_fulfillment            = "${var.wait_for_fulfillment}"
  spot_type                       = "${var.spot_type}"
  instance_interruption_behaviour = "${var.instance_interruption_behaviour}"
  block_duration_minutes          = "${var.block_duration_minutes}"
  tags = {
    Name = "dev-spot"
  }
}
```

Below is the variable file "variable.tf"

```
variable "access_key" {
  default = ""
  } 
variable "secret_key" {
  default = ""
} 

variable "region" {
  default = "us-west-1"
}

variable "key_name" {
  default = "win-key"  
}

variable "windows_spot_price" {
  type        = "string"
  default     = "0.0309"
}
variable "linux_spot_price" {
  type        = "string"
  default     = "0.0125"
}
variable "wait_for_fulfillment" {
  default     = false
}
variable "spot_type" {
  type        = "string"
  default     = "one-time"
}
variable "instance_interruption_behaviour" {
  type        = "string"
  default     = "terminate"
}

variable "block_duration_minutes" {
  type        = "string"
  default     = "0"
}

variable "ami_web" {
  default = "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

The created Spot instance should have an validity to set as 1 hour or 2 hour which I can call from variable.tf file so the Spot instance should be Terminated by 1 hour or 2 hours (or Spot instance request should be cancelled)

Is there a way I can Spin aws ec2 Spot instance with expiry ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to schedule instances for termination.
However, you can use CloudWatch Events and Lambda to create your own instance termination logic. You need to create a [scheduled event](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_rule.html#schedule_expression) in Terraform according to your variable (valid_until), which invokes a Lambda function to terminate the instance.

AWS also has a solution called [Instance Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler). You can simply attach tags to your spot instances to create start/stop schedules.
However, you should change instance stop behaviour in this case, which is by default  shutdown, to terminate. Thus, your instances will be terminated when stopped. This can be achieved by using aws_instance.instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior argument in Terraform.